# how to remove quotation mark from string in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, logic

i am new to javascript. i have paragraph and split them using  str.split('.'). Also i need to remove quotation marks from string after split method. How to eliminate them?

> My mamma stood up and lifted a box off the ground. “We’re in America,
> Rune. They speak English here. You’ve been speaking English for as long as
> you’ve been speaking Norwegian. It’s time to use it.”

and i want the result like

> My mamma stood up and lifted a box off the ground. We’re in America,
> Rune. They speak English here. You’ve been speaking English for as long as
> you’ve been speaking Norwegian. It’s time to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to remove all quotation marks before splitting the array.

```js
const paragraph = `My mamma stood up and lifted a box off the ground. “We’re in America, Rune. They speak English here. You’ve been speaking English for as long as you’ve been speaking Norwegian. It’s time to use it.”`.replace(/“|”/g,'');

console.log(paragraph);
// "My mamma stood up and lifted a box off the ground. We’re in America, Rune. They speak English here. You’ve been speaking English for as long as you’ve been speaking Norwegian. It’s time to use it."
```

If you insist on splitting the array first, you should loop/map over each sentence after you `.split`.

```js
const sentences = `My mamma stood up and lifted a box off the ground. “We’re in America, Rune. They speak English here. You’ve been speaking English for as long as you’ve been speaking Norwegian. It’s time to use it.”`.split('.');

const result = result = sentences.map(sentence => sentence.replace(/“|”/g,''));

console.log(result);
/*
[
   "My mamma stood up and lifted a box off the ground",
   " We’re in America, Rune",
   " They speak English here",
   " You’ve been speaking English for as long as you’ve been speaking Norwegian",
   " It’s time to use it",
   ""
];
*/
```

As you can see, you end up with an empty string as the last item. To get rid of that you could also use `.filter()`.

```js
result = sentences.map(sentence => sentence.replace(/“|”/g,'')).filter(sentence => sentence);
```

To get rid of the whitespace, you could also use `.trim()`.

So to put all of this together:

```js
const sentences = `My mamma stood up and lifted a box off the ground. “We’re in America, Rune. They speak English here. You’ve been speaking English for as long as you’ve been speaking Norwegian. It’s time to use it.”`.split('.');

const result = sentences
  .map(sentence => sentence.replace(/“|”/g, '').trim())
  .filter(sentence => sentence);

console.log(result);

/*
[
  "My mamma stood up and lifted a box off the ground",
  "We’re in America, Rune",
  "They speak English here",
  "You’ve been speaking English for as long as you’ve been speaking Norwegian",
  "It’s time to use it"
]
*/
```

Comment: @dedho i had issues typing quotation marks now problem solved.but at some places (**We’re in America,\nRune**)/n is included. How to eleminate them?.

Comment: @Trunks that's a new line character. If you want to get rid of it, you could do it in a similar way you got rid of quotation marks. `sentence.replace(/\n/g, ' ').trim())`. Here you are replacing each instance of a new line with an empty space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace),

```js
const p = 'My mamma stood up and lifted a box off the ground. “We’re in America, Rune. They speak English here. You’ve been speaking English for as long as you’ve been speaking Norwegian. It’s time to use it.”';

const regex = /“|”/g;

console.log(p.replace(regex, ''));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).